# Textbook recommendation for measure-theoretic stochastic process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, soft-question

I am seeking for a great book on graduate-level, **measure-theory based** book on stochastic process, the ones I can find are [this book by Cosma Rohilla Shalizi and Aryeh Kontorovich](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/almost-none/), and [Foundations of Modern Probability](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387953132)

I can find a lot of classic book on stochastic process, like Stochastic Processes by Ross, and Introduction to Stochastic Processes by Lawler, but they do not have a measure-theoretic framework, so I wonder if there are some well recognized book in this area?

Comment: A very often cited book is the one by Karatzas and Shreve, however it is said to be quite advanced.

Comment: Varadhan also has notes on stochastic processes, available on his website.

Comment: Plus one for Karatzas and Shreve. I also like the introductory textbook of E. Cinlar "Probability and Stochastics".

Comment: Topics in Stochastic Processes by Ash and Gardner is a good companion book.